# Forward operators in haxe

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to write my own boolean "abstract" with some additional functions.

```
@forward
abstract MyBool(Bool) {
  public inline function new(b:Bool) {
    this = b;
  }
  @:from
  public static inline function fromBool(b:Bool):MyBool {
    return new MyBool(b);
  }
  @:to
  public inline function toBool():Bool {
    return this;
  }
  // some additional functions
}
```

In principal this works fine:

```
var t:T = true;
if(t) {
  trace("1");
}
t.someStrangeMethod();
```

However @:forward does not forward basic boolean-operators like "!":

```
var f:T = false;
if(!f) { // fails here, because "!" is not defined as an operator for MyBool ...
  trace("2");
}
```

The error message is "MyBool should be Bool", which I find quite strange because MyBool is an abstract of a Bool with @:forward annotation *and* there is a @:to-method.

Of course there are some easy workarounds. One could either use:

```
if(!f.toBool()) {
  trace("2");
}
```

and/or add a function annotated with @:op(!A) to the abstract:

```
@:op(!A)
public inline function notOp():Bool {
  return !this;
}
```

However I do not like both methods:

- I dislike adding @:op(...) to MyBool, because creating a method for each possible operator would require much code (Maybe not with a boolean, but e.g. with an Int, Float, ...).
- I dislike using !var.toBool(). If someone has already written quite some code (s)he does not want to go through all of it, when (s)he simply wants to change Bool to a MyBool ... I mean of course (s)he could also cast Bool to MyBool whenever adding new code, but that can be horrible too.

So I was wondering if anyone has a better idea? Is there maybe another "@:forward"-like compiling metadata, I do not know about yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open feature request regarding this:

[Can @:forward also forward underlying operator overloads? (#5035)](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5035)

One way to make your code example work is to allow implicit conversions with `to Bool`. I'm not entirely sure why the equivalent `@:to` function doesn't work here, as the Haxe Manual states that ["Class field casts have the same semantics"](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html).

```
abstract MyBool(Bool) to Bool {
```

Apart from that, I think the only options is to declare an `@:op` function for each operator you want to support. If declared without a body, the underlying type's operator will be forwarded:

```
@:op(!A) function notOp():MyBool;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to just add methods to the `Bool` type, then perhaps avoid the problem altogether by instead creating a class that adds methods to Bool via static extension (documented in the Haxe manual). This method would eliminate the need for operator forwarding.